# Chrome Native Messaging API on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extension

I am walking through the Chrome Native Messaging API guide,

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

A sample host's manifest looks like this,

```
{
  "name": "com.my_company.my_application",
  "description": "My Application",
  "path": "C:\\Program Files\\My Application\\chrome_native_messaging_host.exe",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
  ]
}
```

where "path" refers to the app Chrome extension will communicate with. On Windows, either a python script or an exe file will work and will be executed. On Mac OS, I can only get a shell script or a python script to work. I cannot get an .app to be executed.

What I cannot get working is,

```
"path": "/Applications/Skype.app"
```

When I do `"chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName)"` in the extension, the error info is "Native host has exited." Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> On Windows, either a python script or an exe file will work and will be executed. On Mac OS, I can only get a shell script or a python script to work. I cannot get an .app to be executed.

The `.app` is a directory, not a file. Using your example, the actual executable for Skype is probably at `/Applications/Skype.app/Contents/MacOS/Skype`.

Right-click a `.app` in Finder & select "Show Package Contents" to see inside.

Comment: This does not work. I already changed to /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/MacOS/Skype. When I do chrome.runtime.connectNative, the extension will not bring up Skype as it does on Windows

Comment: My expected use case is, when Skype is not open, I do chrome.runtime.connectNative and Skype will be open automatically. The Chrome extension on Windows does it.

Comment: Does `/Applications/Skype.app/Contents/MacOS/Skype` work from Terminal? If all you need to do is launch Skype, you could just do `open -b com.skype.skype` from a shell script.

Comment: That will work and I can run it from the command line, but I do not want to let the extension call a shell script, otherwise my software consists of an extension, a shell script and an application, which makes the software less secure. The shell script might be subject to attacks

Comment: Actually you know what? You are right. I changed the "path" but I forgot to install the json. After I installed it, it work. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. You can give specifics? I am having the same issue. Do you mean that your json manifest in mac didn't got the correct path to the executable? And di you use a shell script? Thanks