# Chrome Extension Native Messaging Doesn't Work on MacOS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm building a Chrome Extension which uses Native Messaging however I am running into an issue when running it in the normal manor.

If I launch Chrome normally the native message does not come through, however if I launch Chrome via it's binary (which is located at `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`) the native message will come through.

Any ideas as to what's happening?

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I have made a dummy native app shell script which simply echoes stdin back, and also dumps to log file. I can see that shell script gets started up, but it never receives anything from stdin.

Comment: Hi. Anyone found solution to this?
I am on the same boat here.

Comment: @Kyle Decot have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31308720/1968739? it worked for me. it's because the `.app` is not a file itself but a folder, hence you need to specify the executable which is the directory you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Take note of this from [Native Messaging docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging):

> On OS X and Linux, the location of the native messaging host's
>   manifest file varies by the browser (Google Chrome or Chromium). The
>   system-wide native messaging hosts are looked up at a fixed location,
>   while the user-level native messaging hosts are looked up in a
>   subdirectory within the [user profile
>   directory](https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory)
>   called NativeMessagingHosts.

```
OS X (system-wide)
Google Chrome: /Library/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/com.my_company.my_application.json
Chromium: /Library/Application Support/Chromium/NativeMessagingHosts/com.my_company.my_application.json
OS X (user-specific, default path)
Google Chrome: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/com.my_company.my_application.json
Chromium: ~/Library/Application Support/Chromium/NativeMessagingHosts/com.my_company.my_application.json
```